# Format date in SendGrid template portal

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid portal to manage my email templates using handlebar substitutions as its reference in this link https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/using-handlebars/#substitution

I would like to know if it is possible to convert and/or format dates in the SendGrid transactional template portal.

This is my HTML template in SendGrid portal:

```
<p>This report was generated on {{GenerationTimeUtc}}</p>
```

This is the dynamic data sent to SendGrid:

```
{
   "GenerationTimeUtc":"2018-09-14T21:16:30.1467851Z"
}
```

I would like to show it in a more readable way like **"This report was generated on May 04"** instead of showing **"This report was generated on 2018-09-14T21:16:30.1467851Z"**

I'm using SendGrid V3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't just send the date formatted in the json?

Comment: Yes, but that means I'll need to change my code each time the user needs to change the date format. It would be easier if I can change only the template

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of [`formatDate`](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#formatdate) for this type of formatting, referencing standard dateTime format flags.

```
<p>Join us {{formatDate dateString "M d"}}</p>
```

And similar implementation using a different date format…

```
<p>Join us {{formatDate dateString "yyyy-mm-dd"}}</p>
```

Comment: The link listed above no longer mentions `formatDate` and I couldn't find any reference to it in the Handlebars.js docs.  **However**, it totally works, so I'm going to use this.